# Why index scan used for a different date? Some date, it will use index seek

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, sql-execution-plan, force-index

Table size is about 40 gb with about 98 million rows.

I have a simple query, selecting the min/max id from a table for 1 day data. By entering a different date, query plan changed to index scan instead of index seek, which is running for a long time. The row count for a day is quite standard about 20-30 thousands. The table has an index for `testtimestamp` column but somehow for certain dates, SQL Server just doesn't use the index. For such case if I using index hint, it will return within seconds.

[image: See screenshot here]

This image shows SQL Server using index scan after the date is changed

[image: Screenshot #2]

When using index hint, it will use the correct index. Question is why the change of date will have a different plan?

[image: Screenshot #3]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Most likely different row count estimates due to the different date values result in different plan. Verify stats are up-to-date and upload the actual execution plans [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: thanks for your feedback. actually i noticed the row count is less when the index scan happened (around 3 thousand rows), the only different in the query is the date range.for the date range with Index Seek it was 30 thousands rows. that makes me cracking my head. Here is the plan for Index Scan
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H14FE8XNL